# Glitches in smplayer playing fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen, smplayer

When I play a video fullscreen in smplayer, I get graphical glitches in a horizontal line about a quarter of the screen from the top, particularly visible if I skip a few seconds, but also when there's a significant change.

I have a fairly recent Nvidia gpu and an LCD monitor. The issue was there in 15.04 and it's still there in 15.10. It does not occur in full screen, nor does it happen with VLC or the default movies app. Any ideas?

Comment: First, do you have Nvidia drivers ? Probably, so try, open smplayer and go to options >> preferences >> Video and change the `output driver`, `vdpau` is Nvidia, `XV` is default, `gl` is fastest, try a few, do any of these fix the issue.

Comment: @markkirby: Thanks, changing it to vdpau fixed the issue. If you would post this as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the **Output driver** in SMplayer to the Nvidia `vdpau` driver.

Open SMplayer and go to **Options > Preferences > Video** and change the **Output driver** to `vdpau`.

[image: SMPlayer interface]